# How to check which gemset rbenv is using?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rbenv

I use `echo project-name > .rbenv-gemsets` to create a new gemset for rbenv.

How do you check to see that it is using this gemset?

`gem list` is empty for the global gemset, so when I run it on the new gemset it doesn't tell me anything.

Comment: did you try a `rbenv gemset list` ?

Comment: No. I tried it now. I don't know how it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do a `rbenv gemset active`

If you've set up rbenv, and rbenv-gemset correctly, you will see the following output:

> project-name global

Comment: Why does it show both `project-name` and `global`? Is `global` active too, somehow?

Comment: Yup. I guess the documentation around this use case isnt particularly strong (it's missing!), but see https://github.com/jf/rbenv-gemset/issues/16, https://github.com/jf/rbenv-gemset/issues/18, and https://github.com/jf/rbenv-gemset/pull/20